# Correction of -0.5 in percentile formula

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, percentile

My question is about how to calculate the percentile of a list of numbers. I found on the Internet the formula:

$$p_i=100·\frac{i-0.5}{N}$$

Nevertheless, I don't understand the reason of -0.5. I mean, for example if I have the following ranked list of numbers:

$$1, 2, 4, 5, 100$$

In my opinion, 100 should be the 100%p and not:

$$p_5=100·\frac{5-0.5}{5} = 90\%$$

I am assuming that all the numbers have the same probability. In this way I'm having the same problem with another formula that is commonly used in this type of calculations:

$$p=100·\frac{i}{n+1}$$

I found this formulas in the following websites:

https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/anthsci/anthsci192/anthsci192.1064/handouts/calculating%20percentiles.pdf

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc262.htm

Thanks for you help!

Comment: it's an interpolation formula. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#First_Variant.2C_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-0000002D-QINU.60.22.27.7F

Comment: [More specific version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#First_variant,_C_=_1/2) of @user126540's link.

Answer (score 1):

Many different formulas for percentile are in common use, and the differences
among these formulas are especially noticeable for small samples. An important
reason for the different methods is that some focus on describing the *sample* and some focus on making inferences about the *population* from which the sample
was drawn.

R statistical software implements nine different 'types' of quantiles in
common use by various textbook authors and software packages; *none* of them seem
to use the formula you found on the Internet. I have posted output from
some of them below. [Without extra 'arguments', the R function 'quantile' gives quantiles 0%, 25% (lower quartile), 50% (median), 75% (upper quartile)
and 100%, according to what it calls 'Type 7'.]

```
quantile(x)                  # the 'default' method in R
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   1    2    4    5  100 
quantile(x, type=4)
    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
  1.00   1.25   3.00   4.75 100.00 
quantile(x, type=6)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
  1.0   1.5   4.0  52.5 100.0 
quantile(x, type=8)
        0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
  1.000000   1.666667   4.000000  36.666667 100.000000 
quantile(x, type=9)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
  1.0000   1.6875   4.0000  34.6875 100.0000
```

Notice that all of them say that observation 100 (the maximum observation)
is the 100th percentile. Of course, this does not guarantee that 100 is
the maximum possible observation in the population from which your sample
was drawn.

With so many different methods in use, and without knowing the credentials
of the author of the Internet site where you found the formula, it would
be foolish for me to say that the formula you found is "wrong." But this
formula is certainly not in the mainstream. If you don't like its results,
you should certainly feel free to shop around for a method you like better.

*Note:* As a general policy, you should always be skeptical of technical
information you find via Google searches. 
For statistical issues, it is best to rely on sites of government agencies,
statistical organizations, and *statistics* departments at major universities. I have often found
the online handbook of the US agency NIST to be helpful.  For
example, [*this page*](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc262.htm).

Answer (score -1):

For your numbers 1,2,4,5,100 each number represents 20% of the distribution. The first number 1 is 0%-20%, therefore we want a formula which gives 10% as a point value of the percentile. The final number is 80%-100% and so we want 90% as the result.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the max of the set is not in the 100th percentile.

Comment: @SlugPue I believe it does. The max is the 80th to 100th percentile because it is 20% of the distribution.

Comment: it's just a particular interpretation of what a sample percentile is. Normally you would say that a sample percentile is the value for which the sample is less or equal to that value. It's not clear from your answer whether you think this is a standard method of calculating percentiles or if it's some interpolation technique.

Comment: And what about $$p=100⋅\frac{i}{n+1}$$?